# Resolver returning empty array but cause is not identifiable

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, graphql, apollo

I have a mutation which has a resolver that simply inserts a record into the database, but the problem is that `createPost` keeps on returning an empty array and as a result I'm getting this error `"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Post.text."`

`Mutation/index.js`

```js
import { query } from "@/server/db";

export const createPost = async (_, { post }) => {
  const createPost = await query(
    `
    INSERT INTO posts (text, user_id)
    VALUES (?, ?)
  `,
    [post.text, post.user_id]
  );
  console.log(createPost);
  return createPost;
};
```

Comment: A DB insertion function\action does not necessarily returns the inserted values, it may return a success\ failure indicator or nothing at all.

Comment: How do I check for failure?

Comment: I am not particularly familiar with sqlite, but a quick google search suggested [this](https://sqlite.org/lang_returning.html). Hope it helps you

Comment: Hello, the insertion works, but what do you think I should return. Should it be `[post.text,post.user_id]`?

Comment: I got this to work! I just returned `post`

Comment: Returning `post` will return the value of the `post` variable not the records that were actually inserted into the db. e.g. even if the insertion fails for whatever reason, it will still return the same value, as `post` is holding **the value that was sent from the server to the db**, while what you really want is to return the value **from the db to the server**

Comment: what was loggod? mutation return type defs?

Answer (score 0):

According to sqlite docs (linked in the comment above), adding a `RETURNING` clause to the query, like bellow:

```
const createPost = await query(
    `
    INSERT INTO posts (text, user_id)
    VALUES (?, ?)
  `,
    [post.text, post.user_id]
    RETURNING *
  );
```

Will return the newly inserted values from the DB, thus, it will become the value of `createPost`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I followed this and then it said `,` expected, but after adding that I got `expression expected` error

Comment: As I stated above, I am not particularly familiar with sqlite \ graphql. it was a suggestion taken from the docs that shows **the concept** of returning inserted docs, you'll have to search around for the exact way and syntax of doing it, and are welcome to edit the answer as well.

Comment: I think my sqlite version doesn't support `RETURNING` is there another way to do this?